# Filter/REPLACE certain characters in data retrieval in database

Tags: php, mysql

I provide search form on blog. So everyone can find articles using certain keywords.

**Sample script:**

```
<?
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['search']);

$sql = $connection->query("SELECT post_url, post_title FROM mytable WHERE post_title LIKE '%{$search}%'");
$num = $sql->num_rows;

if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {

    echo "<li><a href='/post/" . $row['post_url'] . "'>"  . $row['post_title'] . "</a></li>";

        }
} else {
    echo "NO RESULTS";
}
?>
```

For example, I have a post page with a title **i didn't know**

When someone tries to search by keyword "`i didn't know`", then what to look for will be displayed.

Whereas if someone wrote it with "`i didnt know`", (without single quotes), then the result is "**NO RESULTS**".

So how to ignore (single quotes) so that posts can be found using keywords "`i didnt know`"?

Comment: you could have a second column with the title excluding all special characters and try to match against that column as well as the title column ?